# Getting weird error using Phpmailer() function

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send mail from my php code. The mail is getting delivered but i am getting this error on the page.
MyCODE:

```
require("class.phpmailer.php"); 
$mail = new PHPMailer(); $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP             $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure='ssl'; $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Port= 465;
 $mail->Username = ""; 
$mail->Password = ""; 
$mail->SetFrom = "*"; 
$mail->AddAddress($mail_name); 
$mail->Subject = "Transfer Money"; 
$mail->Body = $message; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
 echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
```

}

SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2015-07-27 07:19:23  CLIENT -> SERVER: dmluZWVsMTIzMjFAZ21haWwuY29t 2015-07-27 07:19:23  CLIENT -> SERVER: dmlubnkxMzY2 2015-07-27 07:19:23  CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 2015-07-27 07:19:23    CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 2015-07-27 07:19:23  CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 2015-07-27 07:19:23  CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2015 09:19:22 +0200 2015-07-27 07:19:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: Return-Path: root@localhost 2015-07-27 07:19:23   CLIENT -> SERVER: To: xxxxxx@gmail.com 2015-07-27 07:19:23  CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Root User 2015-07-27 07:19:23   CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Transfer Money 2015-07-27 07:19:23   CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <899d1f02dfa5fee9688871f8aa804f42@localhost> 2015-07-27 07:19:23  CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3 2015-07-27 07:19:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.4 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) 2015-07-27 07:19:23   CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 2015-07-27 07:19:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 2015-07-27 07:19:23   CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 2015-07-27 2015-07-27 07:19:23    CLIENT -> SERVER: 2015-07-27 07:19:23   CLIENT -> SERVER: . 2015-07-27 07:19:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT mail Not sent

Comment: What have you tried? Does the normal php [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function work? How is the server setup? Can you give a bit more background information.

Comment: You should edit the question and put it there format-et. This just makes a big mess.

Comment: Update your phpmailer. 5.2.4 is buggy and ancient.